# Is order of selection in Spatial Data important (attribute, location, graphic)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-database, select, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

When dealing with spatial data in a GIS system, does it matter which way you select the information if you're using all 3 - attribute location and graphical selection? In my experience it seems to not matter, but I wanted to confirm this.

Comment: Yes. It matters for performance reasons. Attribute queries are faster than spatial queries (generally); there are a few exceptions to the rule due to spatial indexing. If you've already got it limited to a selection then there's only a few to test so the query runs much faster.

Comment: Attribute queries are only faster if they're more selective. ArcObjects gives the option to choose attribute-first on spatial queries to geodatabases. If the search is pure SQL (as in a Query Layer), then optimizer hints are necessary.

Comment: Yes @Vince, it depends on a lot of factors which is faster, indexing (spatial and attribute) the complexity of the SQL statement or geometry, joined/related tables. The programmer/user needs to make that call on a case by case basis... in general though an attribute selection is faster than a spatial selection (graphic selection is a type of spatial selection). Normally I notice a performance increase on an ISpatialFilter with a whereclause if I use attributes first, likewise in ArcMap if you select by attributes then select from by location it's normally faster than the other way around.

Comment: The other variable is spatial fragmentation. I spent a year researching performance in large and very large spatiotemporal data tables, and found that spatially defragmentated tables always performed well in spatial-first queries, even if the attributes were slightly to moderately more selective.